# Mapping regular SQL to Drupal's Database API - using 'exists'?

Tags: 7, database

I have the following SQL that I'm trying to translate using Drupal's Database API:

```
select nid,biblio_type from biblio where not exists
    (select * from biblio_types where biblio_type = tid);
```

What would the translation be?  Currently I have this which is not working:

```
$sub_query = db_select('biblio_types','bt');
$sub_query->fields('bt',array('tid'))
         ->condition('biblio_type','tid','=');
$query = db_select('biblio','b');
$query->fields('b',array('biblio_type'))
      ->notExists($sub_query);
$result = $query->execute();
```

**EDIT #1**: Changed `exists` to `notExists`.

**EDIT #2**:

After changing `exists` to `notExists` and replacing the condition statement in the subquery with `where` per Clive's instructions, this is the SQL that is placed in `$result->queryString`:

```
SELECT b.biblio_type AS biblio_type
FROM 
biblio b
WHERE  ( NOT EXISTS  (SELECT bt.tid AS tid
FROM 
biblio_types bt
WHERE  (b.biblio_type = bt.tid) ))
```

...which is what I expect.  If I place this statement verbatim in MySQL Query Browser I get the exact results I want.  It returns exactly 9 rows of data.  Perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to use a `where()` for the condition in the subquery, PDO will most likely quote the 'tid' and mess it up.

```
$sub_query->where('bt.biblio_type = b.tid');
```

You can cast a `SelectQuery` to a string to view it's SQL equivalent at any time, it helps a lot with debugging the more complex queries.

```
print (string) $query;
```

Comment: I was actually just going to edit to change `exists` to `notExists`.

Comment: It's probably the subquery condition then, have a look at the SQL for the query after you've added the `notExists()`, it should give you a good insight into what's going on

Comment: Okay super weirdness going on... updating question.

Comment: I'm not completely in the clear yet, see my edit.  Since you answered my original question I'll upvote and mark as accepted.

Comment: Hmm that's a strange one, I can't think of a reason the query wouldn't work in Drupal if it works in the browser. I'll let you know if anything comes to mind

Comment: Just ignore my follow-up question...